# update_user_meta on registration but only for default role type

Tags: user-roles, user-meta

So I am running the following to update user meta on regsitration:

```
function set_user_rcp_default_subscriber($user_id) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp_user_level', '0' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'rcp_subscription_level', '1' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'rcp_status', 'active' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'rcp_expiration', '2014-06-30' );
}

add_action("user_register", "set_user_rcp_default_subscriber", 10, 1);
```

However, I only want this to apply to users that are registered as the default type (subscriber in my case).

Users that are registered with a different role type I dont want to update with these meta values.

Any help very much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

```
function set_user_rcp_default_subscriber($user_id) {
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );  

    foreach( $user->roles as $role ) { 
         if ( $role === 'subscriber' ) {
              update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp_user_level', '0' );
              update_user_meta( $user_id, 'rcp_subscription_level', '1' );
              update_user_meta( $user_id, 'rcp_status', 'active' );
              update_user_meta( $user_id, 'rcp_expiration', '2014-06-30' );
         }
    }
}

add_action("user_register", "set_user_rcp_default_subscriber", 10, 1);
```

We need to loop through it because potentially a user can have multiple roles.

Comment: You don't want to use Vinod Dalvi's answer because many roles have "edit_post" capability and you will get false positive results.

Comment: Thanks for telling me the issue, i have by mistakenly forgotten to add ! in the condition. I have changed the code to make it only work for subscriber user role and it is more optimized code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by checking whether user role is subscribe or not by using [user_can](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can) function and checking it in the user_register action hook  function as following.

```
function set_user_rcp_default_subscriber($user_id) {
   if ( !user_can( $user_id, 'edit_post') ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp_user_level', '0' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'rcp_subscription_level', '1' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'rcp_status', 'active' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'rcp_expiration', '2014-06-30' );
   }
}

add_action("user_register", "set_user_rcp_default_subscriber", 10, 1);
```

Comment: This seems to be somewhat there. I guess to get subscribers I want to exclude all users who can edit_post. The following doesnt seem to work however: `if ( !user_can( $user_id, 'edit_post') ) {...`

Comment: Sorry ... i forgot to add ! in the condition. I have corrected it now.